# Rails 3 HTML 5/javascript free graphing recommendations

Tags: javascript, ruby-on-rails-3, html, graph

In doing searches for good rails 3 graphing options most of the things I can find are a couple of years old and some are not maintained anymore.  A few of the items I found are Bluff, D3, flotr, flotilla, and Highcharts, though Highcharts is not free for commercial use.  I am using prototype so I was looking for a solution with prototype.

I don't need anything too involved.  At the moment I am just planning line graphs but that could change.  Any recommendations on what I could use with prototype?  I would rather not switch my site over to jquery just so I can do graphing.

Thanks in advance for any recommendations.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are going to have a difficult time finding javascript projects that support Rails 3 and Prototype. Although Protoype is still 'supported' it isn't the default so it doesn't receive as much attention. The majority of the web and javascript plugins these days seem to use some sort of jQuery base so I would seriously consider moving your code that way.

Here are some alternatives:

https://github.com/uiteoi/ico (based on Raphael framework)

https://github.com/michelson/lazy_high_charts (HighCharts)

http://people.iola.dk/olau/flot/examples/ (Flot)

Also, Ryan Bates has a [RailsCast](http://railscasts.com/episodes/223-charts) about a number of these options.

Comment: I ended up going with High Charts Last November.  I am fine for now.  I gave up after a couple days of searching, and watched the Rails cast.  For a for profit site, small profit.  I will have to continue to look.

Answer (score 1):

Try using HTML5 canvas api. It has a complete drawing api.